# How serialize Base class properties for multiple derived classes, ProtoBuf.net

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

I'm intereseted if there is any way to serialize base class properties from multiple derived classes without writing [ProtoInclude(n, typeof(DerivedM))] attribute for all derived classes.

Answer (score 1):

That is the preferred mechanism. You *can* automate it via reflection and manipulating the `RuntimeTypeModel[typeof(TheBaseType)]` (there are methods to add sub-types, etc) - however, this is brittle: it is *very* important that the same keys (numbers) map to the same types in the future, even if you add/remove/rename types. Additionally, explicitly declaring the support makes it easy to see which keys (field numbers) are in use.